# How can I run a PHP explode() function when parsing a variable in Stacey?

Tags: php, explode

How can I run a PHP explode() function on a variable called "artist" in [Stacey](http://staceyapp.com/)?

I've been digging around in /app/asset-types/page.inc.php around line 49 "#magic variable assignment", but I don't have enough PHP experience to understand what's going on.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the variable 'artist' coming from? Can you explain what you are trying to do. Looking at the code the __set method on line 49 seems to be for setting template variables.

Comment: I've created my own variable called "artist". If you look at how the system works you can name variables in your .txt files and access them in the HTML with the @ symbol.  For example, the "title" variable is accessed in your HTML templates with `@title`.